# Always getting back an, "Internal Server Error," when trying to run ban command on my Discord bot

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have tried many different ways of formatting the code, however, whenever I add code so that I must provide a reasoning to ban someone, I am always given an Internal Server Error. Here is my code.

```js
module.exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {

  const member = message.mentions.members.first();
  const reason = args.slice(1).join(" ")

  if (!message.member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) {
    return message.reply("you lack sufficiant permissions to execute this command.");
  } else if (member.hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR")) {
    message.reply("you cannot ban this member.")
  }

  member.ban(reason).then((member) => {
    message.channel.send(`${member} has been banned.`);
  });
```

I use a command handler, and all my other commands work fine.

Comment: Which line throws the error?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try changing

```js
member.ban().then((member) =>//
```

to

```js
member.ban({reason : args.slice(1).join(' ')}).then((member) =>//
```

Answer (score 0):

first step: Define the user

```
let user = message.mentions.members.first() || message.guild.members.cache.get(args.join(' '));
```

Second step: Create embed message or normal message

```
const userbanned = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#FF0000')
        .setAuthor('User Banned')
        .setDescription(`**${user.user.username}#${user.user.discriminator}** is now banned from this server`)
        .setFooter(`bot_name`);
```

Third step: Send message

```
user.send(`You were banned from **${message.guild.name}** by ${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator}`)
    return user
        .ban()
        .then(() => message.channel.send(userbanned))
        .catch(error => message.reply("ERROR"));
```